# How to save data between refreshes AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refresh

I am having one object inside my application in $rootScope. I want to save its state somehow when user presses F5 or manually refreshes app.  I have seen examples with $coockies in Angular, but those only save primitive type, and at best I could save object as JSON, and later to restore it from that content.

Is there any example and/or library that can help me do this with not too much coding around for this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the methods putObject and getObject of $cookies.
look here :[$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

Or use the local storage with the JSON functions to parse objects like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('myObject',JSON.stringify({id:'1',name:'test'}))
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myObject'))
```

Comment: I tried $cookies with object, but it doesn't restore anything after F5. Can you write simple example with object being put to $coockies?

Comment: This is the answer, just remember to deserialize object from coockie.

Answer (score 1):

What about using HTML5 Local Storage? You could save the object every time it changes and recall it in the Apps run function.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Can I submit object to localStorage?

Comment: yes like this: localStorage.setItem('myObject',angular.toJson({id:'1',name:'test'})) and to get the object: angular.fromJson(localStorage.getItem('myObject'))